# In android i need to customized cluster icon in mapbox using the colors that are in the annotation in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, markerclusterer

I have to create a customized cluster icon ,the icon will have count of the annotations that are clustered and the cluster icon border should take the colors from the annotation,let say if i have three annotations that are clustered  and all three have different colored annotation icons then the customized cluster icon should have border with three equal parts of color in kotlin using mapbox .[here is the img where clustered icon taking colors from the annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKitD.png).

```
private fun onMapReady() {
    if (username.isNotEmpty()) {
         val clusterOptions = ClusterOptions(
            textColorExpression = color(Color.WHITE),
            textColor = Color.BLACK,
            textSize = 20.0,
            circleRadiusExpression = literal(25.0),
            colorLevels = listOf(
                Pair(100, Color.RED),
                Pair(50, Color.BLUE),
                Pair(0, Color.BLACK)
            )
        )

        val annotationPlugin = binding.mapView.annotations

        pointAnnotationManager = annotationPlugin.createPointAnnotationManager(
            AnnotationConfig(
                annotationSourceOptions = AnnotationSourceOptions(
                    clusterOptions = clusterOptions
                )
            )
        )


        val destinations = listOf(
            Point.fromLngLat(77.6396767, 12.9754017),
            Point.fromLngLat(77.5912, 12.9797),
            Point.fromLngLat(77.088590, 13.339040),
            Point.fromLngLat(77.6212, 12.9797)
        )

        viewModel.getDeviceList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { cariTagDevices ->
            if (cariTagDevices.isNotEmpty()) {
                savedDeviceList = cariTagDevices
                for (i in cariTagDevices.indices) {
                    val device = cariTagDevices[i]
                    if (i < destinations.size) {
                        val iconBitmap = CariTagUtils.getMarkerBitmapFromView(
                            requireContext(),
                            CariTagUtils.getIcon(device.iconId),
                            device.colorValue
                        )
                        if (iconBitmap != null) {
                            prepareAnnotationMarker(iconBitmap, device)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        mapboxMap.loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {
            viewAnnotationManager = binding.mapView.viewAnnotationManager
            circleAnnotationManager = mapView.annotations.createCircleAnnotationManager()
            polylineAnnotationManager = mapView.annotations.createPolylineAnnotationManager()


        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is your exact error? Is the actual behaviour different from the expected behaviour?

Comment: There is no error,i want to customize the custered icon  by fetching the colors from the clustered annotations. do we have a function in map box where i can get the data of clustered points?